# System.Net.Mail code cannot access smtp server

Tags: c#, .net

I'm been using System.Net.Mail to create and send emails via a smtp server with my .Net code. The code for doing this is shown below.

```
            MailMessage message = new MailMessage();
            message.From = new MailAddress(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["fromName"]);
            message.To.Add(new MailAddress(toField));
            message.Subject = GetMessageSubject(File);
            message.Body = GetMessageBody(responseRecords);
            message.IsBodyHtml = true;

            SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient();
            smtpClient.Send(message);
```

the corresponding code in the config file is:

```
<!-- Configuration for specifying SMTP host for sending e-mails-->
  <system.net>
<mailSettings >
  <smtp>
     <network host="smtp-abc123.com" port="25" defaultCredentials="true"/> 
  </smtp>
</mailSettings>
  </system.net>
<appSettings>
<add key="toName" value="abc.123@gmail.com" />
<add key="fromName" value="from@server.com" />
</appSettings>
```

When I run this locally I use credentials corresponding to my local environment and our smtp server. When I deploy the code to the QA department they use their own details and their own smtp server and so change the data in the config file.

This has worked fine in previous deployments. However they are now getting the following error:

```
"Failure sending mail - Unable to connect to the remote server"
```

The .Net code is in a service application that is located on an application server. I logged onto this app server and was able to connect to the smtp server successfully using a telnet command and the credentials in the smtp file.

I don't know what to do next in order to try and resolve this issue.

Comment: you can add username and password to the mailsettings. Otherwise check your firewall log if the SMTP server gets blocked

Answer (score 4):

Check firewall and anti-virus settings to make sure the server and/or port is not getting blocked.

Comment: This is most likely the culprit. I recall how surprised I was the first time my AntiVirus blocked an outbound Mail call on the assumption that my software was some kind of spam bot.

Comment: @John Cruz is it possible for these to block the applicaton but not the telnet command even though both are originating from the same server?

Comment: Yes, it is. By the way, if you're sending via GMAIL, it requires port 587.